# Philosophically, why can't markup be binary data? i.e. Why can't we compile HTML for the web?

Tags: html

Given the vast efforts to make the web as efficient as possible, why can't HTML (and all the various other plain text files e.g. CSS, JavaScript) be compiled into a single resource and sent down the wire? (I'm aware of [.chm files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) - these are along the lines of this concept).

I understand the open nature of the web - an effort I stand behind - but one could conceive of an open specification that requires multiple resources compile down into binary. Decomplication by the user-agent could be required by the specification (this allowing individuals to view the DOM etc.)

I guess I'm just surprised, given the efforts at performance in other areas, we're still relying on plain text to push around pages, or am I just over-estimating the savings a binary format would provide?

Comment: Don't have an answer, but +1 for really awesome question!

Comment: I guess it's just the legacy how the web developed. But your suggestion sure is interesting.

Comment: the second letter in the abbreviation means text so unless we get hbml it will be test, just saying.

Comment: Imagine troubleshooting the DOM in that scenario.  Not to mention the fact that server-side code would have to decompile it before DOM manipulation.  It just doesn't sound like it would be more efficient at all.

Comment: You're basically saying, let's Zip up all the files needed for a website, send the zipped/compressed file, and have the user unzip it? Too bad I reached my vote cap for today...

Comment: It might be more efficient...the very first time.  Every request after that, you'd waste more bandwidth because in the real world, most of that content will now be cached.

Comment: Well, on the client-side, representations of the DOM have already been processed and rendered by the time you and I get to poke and around in Firebug. They're already in-memory in a binary format, so I'm not sure what the issue is there. I don't know what you mean for your second point about server-side manipulation.

Comment: Wouldn't really need decompilation. The DOM could easily be stored in a format akin to Java's serialization (or python's pickling, etc.). Since the DOM would already be built, it would probably be more efficient on the client side, since it wouldn't have to parse and build. Instead, it could just deserialize an object map.

Comment: Another thing would be re-training lots of web developers who weren't necessarily trained as real programmers. The gain in web efficiency might be useful to some companies (say, PayPal or eBay) and not useful at all to others (say, a small university). Having a really really really low barrier-to-entry way to develop web pages is economically reasonable for them. Thus, perhaps not a lot of incentive to develop tools along the lines you mention.

Comment: @EMS I think the idea would be to be as transparent as possible. We'd still be writing HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but it would be compiled, either once, or on-the-fly (and cached). But you do have a point.

Comment: I think we could keep the BtE down. Pages could be developed as they are today (and browsers would continue to parse old-fashioned HTML, at least for a while). Then, when it's time to deploy, just compile the project. Maybe.

Comment: @Truth Also, my suggestion goes beyond just compressing the data, but truly compiling and representing the DOM in binary.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam. @Kirk Woll You could even cache the data; if the binary hasn't changed, just rerun the local copy.

Comment: Off-topic here, I'm afraid. :) This is not a programming (code) question; it's more theoretical, and therefore doesn't belong here. I've voted to migrate it to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) where it may be a better fit. (It's also inappropriate here because it can't be answered, and therefore doesn't suit SO's Q & A format. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions this type of question as being inappropriate here.)

Comment: @Matt, what if you are on page 2, and 90% of the resources (css, images, javascript) has already been cached from page 1.  With your solution, all that data will have to be redownloaded for page 2.

Comment: Clarifying my comment.  I mistyped "server-side" when I meant "client-side".

Comment: Philosophically, you're asking two different things here: 1) if pre-compiling HTML into a binary DOM representation offers any significant performance benefits, and 2) if there is potential savings in packaging the page together with the resources it references / depends on. The latter, BTW, is already quite possible - you might want to ask these separately...

Comment: @KenWhite I think you might be right. Given the nature of the question, I'm having a hard time picking the "correct" answer to accept.

Comment: :) And just look at the discussion it's caused in the comments alone. <g> Thanks for not taking offense.

Answer (score 4):

An important factor for the development of the web has been the extensibility of the web languages. Browser vendors can support more functionality than the standards require. Although this has always been a hassle for developers, it *has* helped the web forward.

By compiling the web pages you would limit the capabilities to the set that the compiler supports. It would not be possible to use any new features in any browser until the compiler catches up with the development. This would slow down the development of the web.

Comment: Great to read about stuff I hadn't even considered. In this case there's nothing stopping a browser vendor's compiler supporting whatever functionality they wanted, propitiatory or not. I don't see how this would be fundamentally different from what we have now.

Comment: @Matt: You would have to use a single standard compiler for the concept to work at all. If each browser vendor would have their own compiler, then you would have to compile the site for all different browsers that exist. That would be much worse than the browser wars ever was, it would be the dark ages of browsers...

Answer (score 1):

Often web "text" assets (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, XML, JSON) **are "binary"**, since they are served GZIPped: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=gzip+files+server
Hard to get more optimized than that; able to be read by a human, while very compressed.

Comment: Is it fair to say a binary representation of the DOM vs. a compressed, serialized representation of the DOM (which is what HTML could be considered, I suppose) are of comparable size, as much as it makes no difference?

Comment: @Matt Perhaps a "bytecode" compiled version of HTML etc could be parsed slightly faster than a text HTML, & maybe a tiny bit smaller than GZIPped files.  It may be worth while seeing if the major players would look into this.

Comment: ***However**, the major players (MicroSoft/IE, Webkit/Apple/Google, Firefox) have _alot_ on their plate; SPDY/HTTP2, hammering out & implementing HTML5, CSS3, a single platform for web audio/video (still is no single solution), now dynamic serving the proper image resolution to target devices (smartphones vs desktop vs HD iPad3 all need different sized images, & images eat alot of bandwidth/memory), the web devs have ALOT on their plates now.

Comment: Client browser speed often is not an issue, getting data from the internet into the client is often the largest drag on webpage performance.  I do think GZIPped bytecode will be smaller then GZIPped text, so I think your idea can be helpful.  If you want to "make the web faster", there are also other meathods that are in progress that you can join now.   IF you want to do bytecode, start with just JavaScript first.  But are bytecodes for x86 different from ARM?  Is Pentium4 different from i3 CPUs? etc...

Answer (score 0):

There have been attempts at this - see WBXML. However, the problem comes when someone tries to extend the XML definition - does an ID of 35 correspond to the microsoft extension <foo>, or the netscape <bar>?

It's also a lot harder to read the binary when you are trying to work out what bit of the HTML you got wrong.

The main issue of data size was solved by gziping the data before it leaves the web server.